# Website database replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

I have a website that has one database
I have also Desktop apps that have database

I want to replicate the data from the desktop apps databases to website database,
In other word the desktop apps will act as Publishers and distributers and the website will act as a subscriber .It is a central subscriber scenario.

My question is How can I do this ,I mean Is it done through code (RMO or someotherway) or Sql Server 2008 (Transct-SQL)

And How can I add the replication with setup of the desktop app?

and How can I configure website database for replication ?

Please Help me
I have never work on replication before.
I just want someone to explain to me the correct method or way of doing this .
Just main  points as a guideline and I will figure out the rest myself

[image: Central subscriber]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that writing your own solution with SMO or fully ground-up would be too much overhead.

Have you had a look yet at [`Web Synchronization for Merge Replication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151763%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)? It's basically the classic SQL Server pusblisher/subsriber merge replication, but done over Web, through IIS.

You can even set some of your articles read-only at the publisher so the modifications you will make in them at the subscriber will not be brought back (something to emulate transactional replication, if you want to).

Comment: You mean IIS resides in Website (Internet) or locally ? and What if the website is the subscriber and all users (with desktop apps) are the publisher + Distributer?

Comment: @alihaider: If you have a look at the article I linked into my answer then I think this should be clear. IIS needs to be "closer" to the publisher. In your situation, I think you can use the same IIS instance as the one where you published your web site.

Comment: @alihaider: If the desktop application is the publisher then you may want to consider switching roles and make the other side the publisher. I really don't know all your design details in order to give some good advice on this (perhaps you can update your question with more info).

Comment: I realized now I have to install IIS in each user Computer to be a Publisher according to Single Server Topology [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151811(v=sql.105))

Comment: @alihaider: Then perhaps you should think about switching the roles and make the other side the publisher. What problems would you have if you do that?

Comment: I do not understand ,Is not it a common scenario ?!! ,am I the first one to want to update his database website from desktop database app !!! Isn't this Common? I think there is some easier answer for this

Comment: @alihaider: Fine. You're free to wait for someone else to give an answer. But I can tell you now that this is the easiest way there is.

Comment: @alihaider Merge replication is bi-directional changes made flow in both directions so as thecoon says "It's basically the classic SQL Server pusblisher/subsriber merge replication, but done over Web, through IIS.", there's no reason for you to need to have more than one publisher (the web server) to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use SQL Server merge replication via IIS.  I do this with my clients right now and it works great.  I think you're mixing your terms up though, causing more confusion than is necessary.  There is no reason to think of the laptops as 'publishers', at least not in SQL terms.  They can still be subscribers, but if you use merge replication, then that means the laptops will send data both ways (take data from the server, and send data to the server).  My situation is to have a SQL server on our IIS server (or you can separate those servers for a more secure enviro), and synchronize through RMO to the laptops to a WPF application of mine.  These laptops don't need IIS or SQL server installed on them, you can replicate to a SQL Compact database easily using RMO.

Additionally you can look into using WCF, microsoft synchronization services.  But that requires more work i think, and i have less experience there.

Comment: They should have Sql server installed cause they have their own databases installed locally and replicating with website database but thanks for telling me that they do not need IIS installed too